# Nodejs Format Preserving Encryption bad Cipher Output

Tags: node.js, cryptography, aes

I am currently trying to implement the NIST FPE on FF3 mode from this document:
http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-38G.pdf

In there its given an example on various calculations done during steps 1) to 5).
http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/documents/Examples/FF3samples.pdf

At the moment i am getting it all right except 4.iii) (REVB(CIPHREVB(K) REVB(P)).

I have the following code:

```
var reversedP = new Buffer('cd8101000000000000000000730a33fa', 'hex');
var reversedKey = new Buffer('946afc046f6d037f4faa80d5d85943ef', 'hex');
var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-128-ecb', reversedKey);
var cypherText = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(reversedP), cipher.final()]);
var s = reverseArrayToBuffer(cypherText);
```

in my example cypherText =
    0a 30 e9 3e a5 6e b7 bc c7 e1 9a 64 83 9b ec 3a cb e9 f2 60 5f 1c 90 d9 e6 56 42 8e 63 83 11 6f

and s = 
     6f 11 83 63 8e 42 56 e6 d9 90 1c 5f 60 f2 e9 cb 3a ec 9b 83 64 9a e1 c7 bc b7 6e a5 3e e9 30 0a

And according to the nist example it should be something like this:
DE7F3E4A 210E3DFF 346924FB FF750039

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: You can see a working open source implementation in Node at https://github.com/mysto/node-fpe